# Mongoose saving array of array instead of a single array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I´m trying to save an array on MongoDB using mongoose. Here is my model:

```
let itemFields = { "name": { "type": "String", "required": true, "unique": true } };

let modelFields = {
    "name": { "type": "String", "required": true, "unique": true },
    "description": { "type": "String" },
    "options": { "type": "Array", "ref": "SelectOptionItem" },
    "company_id": { "type": "ObjectId", "ref": "Company", "required": true },
    "deleted": { "type": "Boolean", "required": true },
    "createdAt": { "type": "Number" },
    "updatedAt": { "type": "Number" }
};

const SelectOptionItem = new mongoose.Schema(itemFields);
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(modelFields);
```

Later I have the following code to save data:

```
schema.statics.create = async function(context, data) {
    console.log("Saved data:");
    console.log(data);
    let so = new this(data);
    so.save();
}
```

Where I get the following log:

```
 Saved data:
 { name: 'aa',
   description: 'aa',
   options: [ { name: '1' }, { name: '2' } ],
   company_id: '59b2cd9a072e4f28b839aaa0',
   deleted: false,
   createdAt: 1511569192524 }
```

Finally, this is what I´m getting in the mongo console:

```
> db.selectoptions.find({});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a18b7288c688033a4adcb0c"), "name" : "aa", "description" : "aa", "company_id" : ObjectId("59b2cd9a072e4f28b839aaa0"), "deleted" : false, "createdAt" : 1511569192524, "options" : [ [ { "name" : "1" } ], [ { "name" : "2" } ] ], "__v" : 0 }
```

Repair that `options` is being an array of array (`[[]]`). Later when retrieving that data I´m having problems as I´m expecting a single array.

I need to undestand why mongoose is saving an array of array at `options` field and how to solve that.

Comment: which version of mongoose you are using ?

Comment: Mongoose Version 4.11.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

- First, by not creating a separate collection for `SelectOptionItem`
- Second, by creating a new `SelectOptionItem` collection and using `ref`

Using mongoose `4.13.1`. You can try this to insert objects into your array without creating a new collection for `SelectOptionItem`. You can always disable `_id` property for documents in `options` if you don't require it.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var SelectOptionItemSchema= mongoose.Schema({ "name": { "type": "String", "required": true, "unique": true } })

let modelFields = {
    "name": { "type": "String", "required": true, "unique": true },
    "description": { "type": "String" },
    "options": [SelectOptionItemSchema],
    "company_id": { "type": "ObjectId", "ref": "Company", "required": true },
    "deleted": { "type": "Boolean", "required": true },
    "createdAt": { "type": "Number" },
    "updatedAt": { "type": "Number" }
};

var SelectOptionSchema = mongoose.Schema(modelFields)

var SelectOption = mongoose.model('SelectOption', SelectOptionSchema);

var data = { name: 'aa', description: 'aa', options: [ { name: '1' }, { name: '2' } ], company_id: '59b2cd9a072e4f28b839aaa0', deleted: false, createdAt: 1511569192524 }


var newSelectOption = new SelectOption(data)
```

If you want to create a collection for `SelectOptionItem` at any cost then while creating the document you need to send the `SelectOptionItem Ids` in the array for options. Because `ref` is similar to a foreign key.

You can use `.populate` to get the full blown object while querying. Refer to http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html for more querying techniques.

**NOTE:** I am not sure how accurate this is but you most probably would want to send `ObjectId` to the `ref` column.

> Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs.
>   However, you should use ObjectId unless you are an advanced user and
>   have a good reason for doing so.

```
var SelectOptionItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({ "name": { "type": "String", "required": true, "unique": true } })

var SelectOptionItem = mongoose.model('SelectOptionItem', SelectOptionItemSchema);

var firstOptionItem = new SelectOptionItem({name: "1"}); //5a18cfe79a61fd183530d467
var secondOptionItem = new SelectOptionItem({name: "2"}); //5a18d0089a61fd183530d469

let modelFields = {
    "name": { "type": "String", "required": true, "unique": true },
    "description": { "type": "String" },
    "options": [{type: "ObjectId", ref: "SelectOptionItem"}],
    "company_id": { "type": "ObjectId", "ref": "Company", "required": true },
    "deleted": { "type": "Boolean", "required": true },
    "createdAt": { "type": "Number" },
    "updatedAt": { "type": "Number" }
};

var SelectOptionSchema = mongoose.Schema(modelFields)

var SelectOption = mongoose.model('SelectOption', SelectOptionSchema);

var data = { name: 'aa', description: 'aa', options: [ "5a18cfe79a61fd183530d467", "5a18d0089a61fd183530d469" ], company_id: '59b2cd9a072e4f28b839aaa0', deleted: false, createdAt: 1511569192524 }


var newSelectOption = new SelectOption(data)

SelectOption.find({}, function(err, response) { 
    console.log(response)
}).populate('options')
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
"options": { "type": "Array", "ref": "SelectOptionItem" },
```

By this:

```
"options": { "type": "Mixed", "ref": "SelectOptionItem" },
```

Or by this:

```
"options": [SelectOptionItemSchema],
```

The second one generate an `_id` for item

Comment: For some reason options is set to an empty array with this approach in `4.13.1`

Comment: Thanks Nandu, I have edited my answer, please let me know what you think about it.

Comment: Yeah that looks about right but from a schema standpoint, you usually would not put a `ref` on `Mixed` type. Please review my answer as well.